# sql server 2008 full text

Tags: sql-server

just migrated to sql server 2008 for some reason the enable full text checkbox for all my databases are grayed out. any idea why?

i do not see full text in services just full text filter daemon launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the fulltext feature during the migration? Its an optional component so by default will not be installed. You can check if fulltext is installed by querying the [IsFullTextInstalled SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879301.aspx).

Also, how did you migrate? There are specific steps for full-text upgrade that have to be done, see [Full-Text Search Upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142490.aspx).